# Get data from relationship's table

Tags: laravel

I am developing webshop. I have the following relations in my model.

```
shoppingCart -> hasMany -> shoppingCartItem 
shoppingCartItem -> belongTo -> shoppingCart
```

I have in my controller function to get the product_id

```
$product = Product::find($request->get('product_id'))->first();
```

in the product table I have relation with the image. I store the image in different table which has only product_id and image_id.

Now my question is can I get

```
 public function getCart(Request $request)
{
    // get the shoppingCart
    $shoppingCart = $this->loadShoppingCart($request->get('key'));
    $carts = [
        'amount' => $shoppingCart->total_products,
        'price'=>$shoppingCart->total_price
    ];
    // get theimage of the product
    $productImage = Image::with('image_id', $request->get('image_id'));

    return response()->json(['carts','productImage']);
}
```

Comment: I don't know your question, what do you want to get?

Comment: I fixed like that.     $shoppingCart = ShoppingCart::where('key' ,$key)->with('shoppingCartItems', 'shoppingCartItems.product', 'shoppingCartItems.product.images')->first();

Comment: so this problem has been fixed?

Comment: yeah the problem has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

I fixed like that.

```
 $shoppingCart = ShoppingCart::where('key' ,$key)->with('shoppingCartItems', 'shoppingCartItems.product', 'shoppingCartItems.product.images')->first();
```